# How to compile an objective c program under windows with independant MingW

Tags: objective-c, mingw, gnustep

I know how to compile the objective c program using gnustep version of mingw.

But I don't like their shell and I want to use the standard mingw gcc compiler.

I put this gcc bin directory in environment path of course, open command prompt in my helloworld.m directory

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSLog (@"Hello World!");
  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

and type

```
gcc -o hello hello.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

but it doesn't work because it cannot find foundation/foundation.h

How to fix this and if possible avoid hardcoding in hello source code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://blog.lyxite.com/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html) at the end of the post the blogger says to write:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o hello2 hello2.m -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

It seems like you always have to pass through GNUStep

Comment: link no longer available

Comment: Link still not available.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.Modifying command line like below solved my problem.

```
gcc -I"c:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers" -L "c:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries" -o hello hello.m -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```